# Overleaf spellcheker marks all words as errors

Tags: overleaf, spellchecking

I am writing a document using overleaf and spellcheker underlines all words with red, it looks like this:
[image]

How can I fix it? By some reason it did't underline all words in other documents that I wrote.

Comment: Hi - I think this will be marked as off topic, as it isn't related to LaTeX at all, but is a question about Overleaf. Please direct questions about Overleaf to Overleaf support - there is a contact form on the website, and you can also get in touch via support@overleaf.com. 
In this case, you have a non-English language chosen as your spell check language. Please use the Overleaf menu in your project to switch the spell check language to English.

Comment: If you click on the leaf in the upper left, it gives the option to choose which language the document is in. It may be assuming the wrong language.